# android ndk application can not run macrobenchmark?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I develop android with kotlin and ndk.

I also tried all Active ABI: arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a, x86, x86_64.

I also tried my real phone.

[build.gradle.kts (:app)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQqtF.png)

[build.gradle.kts (:macrobenchmark)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ns41y.png)

[ExampleStartupBenchmark.kt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWYAI.png)

[compile failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hawi6.png)